UV absorption mechanism of the wooly hairs of the alpine edelweiss
I've read a paper about this photonic structure with corrugation arranged with gaps of similar wavelength to UV light. but the mechanism of how they interact is unclear to me. I still don't understand how wave length apart corrugation interacts with waves of that length.
here is the paper about it in detail: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15697629/

They are saying the plant is covered with hairs. The form of the hairs is tubules with ribs along the length.
The measured reflectance and absorption of the tubules. It is low in the near UV. This implies that UV absorption is high. They are trying to explain how that works without cell damage.
They suspect the ribs are optical waveguides. That means UV light can propagate along the length of the ribs. Or perhaps the light is transmitted down the interior of the tubules. They speculate that the ribs and/or tubules are fill with water and some impurity that absorbs UV.
Normally a waveguide has a smooth surface. Light from outside does not enter. Light from inside does not leave. They speculate that the surface has enough roughness that outside light can leak in.
It is an interesting paper, but it doesn't claim to prove that things work as they describe.
